# 100 score on Google PageSpeed using AMP plugin? Is that even possible?

Tags: amp-html, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I hired a developer to improve my site loading speed. He suggested using AMP for Wordpress plugin. He got me a perfect 100 score on both Mobile and Desktop. I'm very skeptical about it, as my site is quite heavy and other developers wouldn't even commit to a 90+ score. I'm pretty sure this developer just scammed me - and I would like to know how I can find out?

Can someone please help me diagnose the site to find out if it's authentic? Sounds too good to be true.

Comment: run it through page speed insights, if it scores 100 then odds are it is genuine, drop the URL here in the comments and I will have a look if you want. My site scores 100 so it might just be you found a good developer. With all that being said I am going to vote to close this question as it is opinion based and not a question that fits on stack overflow, but still happy to have a look for you.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie see above link

Comment: @GrahamRitchie why do you think it is opinion based? He asked for help how to debug his issue.

Comment: @stylesuxx it is asking for an opinion on how this could be done, without providing (at the time) anything that we could use to diagnose the problem, so we could only guess on how the developer did it.

Comment: @John Smith - he is likely using 'User Agent Sniffing' - as this is WordPress he is probably using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php to identify the user agent that Lighthouse uses and redirecting.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I see - you are of course right, without the link it is opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Install an user agent switcher in your browser and use the lighthouse user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3116.0 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse
```

opening the URL with this user-agent you can see that only a single image is rendered. This is exaclty what google sees, thus you get a good score.

[image]

Comment: How did he do it? When I visit the site, everything seems normal. Additionally, GTMetrix will not see this page. Interesting...

Comment: +1 confirming what I thought, nice catch, user agent sniffing and serve a page just for search engines. @JohnSmith get this undone immediately as this is likely to cause your site to get blacklisted, get a refund and call out the company who did this on every channel you can so nobody else gets scammed by them, disgraceful!

Comment: As I deprived you of some upvotes I went and upvoted 4 answers you gave @stylesuxx :-)